# SSL verification error when installing cocoapods

Tags: ruby, ssl, cocoapods

What I did `sudo gem install cocoapods`

This is the full message from terminal

```
ERROR:  You must add /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2 to your local trusted store
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - hostname "rubygems.org" does not match the server certificate (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 0: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
```

I have no experience with SSL but I followed a couple of question similar to mine but no luck

What I've tried:

- Download and install the new SHA256 intermediate certificate
- Change hostname from https to http
- Follow this [guide](https://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue) but couldn't copy GlobalSignRootCA.pem to ruby folder
- Use HomeBrew but got another error while installing it

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.7`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: @anothermh do I still use `sudo gem install cocoapods` after installing rvm? Because I still got the same error with that command

Comment: Don't use sudo.

Answer (score 18):

MichaelHuelsen has the correct answer.  Here I will give my step-by-step instructions that worked for me but overwrites the pem file with a large one, so beware if this has sensitive info you might want to not destroy.

1. ID the cert file.

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
"/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem"
```

Tells me where my cert file is.

1. Backup the cert file

```
cp /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem /tmp/cert.pem.bak
```

1. Copy down a full cert file via curl

See: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

```
curl --remote-name --time-cond cacert.pem https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

1. Move the new cacert.pem file to replace the old one

```
mv cacert.pem /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
```

I then ran `gem update --system` to update things, but you may just be ok running your original `gem` command.

Comment: Working great in 2022.

Comment: I was able to follow these steps, but the error still persists

Comment: Working in 2023

Comment: Still same error

Answer (score 5):

I also recommend to read the error message carefully. Often, the default root CAs in the Ruby certificate store are (of course) missing important certificates in the certificate chain. For example, if you are behind a (corporate) proxy.

Since Ruby relies on openssl, you need to find out where your cert file is located.

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
```

It outputs the file that ruby and gem are using, in my case under Windows 10 with Ruby 3.0, it looked similar to this:

```
"C:/Your_Local_Ruby_Install_Path/Ruby30-x64/ssl/cert.pem"
```

The cert.pem is a plain text file with certificate information. You need to download the provide the missing certificate and add it to the cert.pem file.

Afterwards you can use `gem install your_package` without SSL issues with respect to that certificate which was missing earlier.

Answer (score 2):

To Solve the issue

download from https://rubygems.org/pages/download (ZIP for windows)

Unpack into a directory and cd there
Install with: ruby setup.rb (you may need admin/root privilege)

it solved for me

Answer (score 0):

Despite the workarounds given, it would be better to dig into the root of the issue. Your system lacks of AlphaSSL intermediate certificate in the trusted CA pools. You need to update the trusted CA root and intermediate certificates on your machine. One of the best sources is [curl's constantly updated CA certificate storage](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) being pulled from Firefox. Otherwise, you can import the certs manually.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 I had to follow an amended script written by this dude: https://deanpcmad.com/2022/installing-older-ruby-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04/

@MichaelHuelsen's answer pointed me in the right direction, and revealed to me that the pre-compiled version provided in Dean's install has his home path in it.

So I compiled my own and with some adjustments was able to install older versions of Ruby in Ubuntu 22.04.

This may be a slight tangent on this question but nevertheless hope it helps anyone who finds their way here for the same reason.

My [version](https://gist.github.com/defaye/47aa2ca29b17e8ec6315c0bc3118abcf#file-install_older_versions_of_ruby_on_ubuntu_22_04-sh) of the install instructions:

```
mkdir ~/.openssl
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
tar zxvf openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1g
./config --prefix=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g --openssldir=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g
make
make test
make install
rm -rf ~/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g/certs
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs ~/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g/certs
# Ruby 3.0
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g rbenv install 3.0.4
# Ruby 2.7
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g rbenv install 2.7.6
# Ruby 2.6
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g rbenv install 2.6.9
# Ruby 2.5 (No Longer Supported)
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g rbenv install 2.5.9
# Ruby 2.4 (No Longer Supported)
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/home/$USER/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g rbenv install 2.4.10
```

Answer (score 0):

for my case:

### error

`sudo gem install cocoapods` but error:

```
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 0: ok (0)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://ruby.taobao.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected) (https://ruby.taobao.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

### reason

old source invalid (for signature?)

### solution

delete old source, add new valid source

#### steps

```
gem sources --remove https://ruby.taobao.org/
gem sources -a https://gems.ruby-china.com/
```

note:

`gem sources -l`

can check current source.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting a similar error. It was telling me I needed to install my company's cert file. Looking at the SSL error, find `CN=`-- I believe this is "Certificate Name". I'm on Mac OS, so I opened "Keychain Access" and exported the certificate.

Then, to find the location of the cert that ruby is using, I ran:

`ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'`

On Mac OS with openssl installed through homebrew, this yielded:

`/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem`

When I went to look at this file, I found out that it's actually a symlink to another cert file. This is because I am using the `certifi` python library (as well as `pyenv`). Running `l` in the `openssl@1.1` directory shows the symlink:

`cert.pem -> ../../../../Users/<USERNAME>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`

I got the gem to install after concatenating my company's cert to this original cert file. I did so by running the following command (in the `~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi/` directory)

`cat ~/path/to/my/exported/cert/MyCompanyCert.pem cacert.pem > cacert.pem`

This appends the company cert to the end of the existing cert file. Et voila. `gem install <package>` to your heart's desire.